# Running GCM Demo app in the Android emulator instead of the API emulator

Tags: android, emulation, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed the instructions given in [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) page to develop the GCM demo app. The application is working fine in the API emulator. How to modify the app such that it runs in the normal Android emulator, or maybe a real device?

Comment: You just have to configure environment to support it and it will works. Read the link that you have given in your question.

Comment: went through the link. it said "This example assumes there is an AVD (Android Virtual Device) named my_avd previously configured with Android 2.2 and Google APIs level 8." Couldn't figure out much. I'm sort of new in android development. Could you please elaborate the process a bit more precisely?